# Center text correctly in background color

Tags: css, reactjs, sidebar

So, basically I have a sidebar and it contains text which is `divs` like overview, settings, etc...
like this:

[image: div]

So, what I need is to create a background color which is white when I hover on the text. I managed to do that and this was the result:

[image: what i did]

So, as you can see the text is not centered inside the background color.

Therefore what I did is to assign `align-items:center` and it worked like this:

[image: fix]

But now my problem is the text is not fixed. meaning when I applied align-items the background remained in the same position but the text moved to occupy the center position. I don't want the text to move I want the text to remain at the same position but the background color to move to cover it and make the text center

div:

```
const style={
        cursor: "pointer",
        height:"30px"
    };

    return (
        <div 
            name={name}
            title = {title}
            style={style}
            onClick={() => onSelect(name)}
            className={selected ? 'selected' : 'hovered'}>
           <div style={{paddingLeft: "10px"}} className="last-hope">{name}</div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
.hovered:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #57c0e8;
    padding-left: 3px;
    border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px lightgray;
    display:flex; 
    align-items:center;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left:3px;
}
```

Hope you understood what my problem is and you can help thank you in advance!!

Comment: Did you try `text-align: center;`? Can you provide a complete static example? The `title` attribute on regular plain text is redundant.

Comment: `.hovered{ align-items:center;}` give a try by giving this css.

Comment: @SavanPadaliya if you can look at the css i did but the problem is the text is moving to the center i want the background to cover the text and the text be centered but not moving its place to cover the center area

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik the title is just the word overview as a string and i tried text-align center didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the styles to the DIV itself, not only to its hovered state:

```
const style={
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
        cursor: "pointer",
        height:"30px"
};
```

Comment: OMG!!!! thank youuuuu soooooo muchhhh it workeddd perfectlyyy thank you thank you !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you said, you want a padding around the text 'Overview'.

From the code you have given, I suppose you are putting up a div on hover. If that's the case, a div takes up all the horizontal space by default. You can limit that by giving it a width.

But based on what you want, you turn on the padding on hover.

**HTML:**

`<p class="decorate">Overview</p>`

**CSS:**

```
.decorate{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.decorate:hover{
  background-color: white;
  //add box radius property to round the edges
}
```